# Why are multiple touches causing my iPhone app to crash?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

In my app, I am getting the row index as the user taps on the row or selected row. But if a row is tapped twice, my app crashes.

What could be causing this behavior, and how can I fix it? Here's the code I'm using:

```
(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{

    abc *xyz = [[abc alloc] init];
    dcs = [allHadits objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    hk = dcs.kokid;
    [dcs release];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean tapping on the same row twice makes it crash? If so, it might be because of the `[dcs release]`. I don't know what dcs is (unless that's supposed to be xyz) but grabbing a pointer to the object in the array and then calling release on it might be releasing the object in the array, making it crash next time the row is hit. Delete the `[dcs release]` and see if it still crashes. My memory management isn't the greatest though so I could be wrong.

Comment: This is most likely the right answer.  The [dcs release] is logically wrong. If the intent is to remove dcs from the array, then [allHadits removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row] would be the correct technique, followed by a call to reloadData for the hosting table view.

Comment: dcs is object, i have comment that release it , now its working alrite thank u soo much, but tell me if we didnt releas objct it will create a problem or not ??? in term of memory management

Comment: dcs is object, i have comment that release it , now its working alrite thank u soo much, but tell me if we didnt releas objct it will create a problem or not ??? in term of memory management

Comment: @Hasseb No problem. And not releasing it will not cause any problems because releasing the array later will release the objects inside. Can you please  select my answer as the answer to the question. Trying to build reputation. Thanks!

Comment: i am new to stack its giving me some 15 repution prblm

Answer (score 0):

Don't release dcs. Why are your variables named so poorly?

Comment: and also check me another problem :)        
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929960/table-reloaddata-not-working

Comment: now problem is solve but let me know it will create any problm in memory managment term?

Comment: I highly recommend studying Objective-C memory management. You aren't going to get very far without understanding it.