# table reloadData not working

Tags: iphone, ipad, iphone-sdk-3.0

i am using following code to delet a row from tableview as well from db ,
the row is delted from the db at once but its not delted from the tableview till i back back and th chk aggain ,i want when i delet the row tableview should rload the data...
 any idea ?

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle 
forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    [self.table beginUpdates];

  if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) 
  { 
    Hadits *delHadit = [self.allBookMarks objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    dbAccess *dbmethods = [[dbAccess alloc] init]; 
    NSInteger delHaditid = delHadit.haditid;
    [dbmethods deleteBookMark:delHaditid];
    [dbmethods release];    
  }
  [self.table reloadData];//its not working reload data...
  [table endUpdates];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Include this line,

```
[self.allBookMarks removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

**EDIT:**

The problem is not with reloadData, the problem is that you are not updating your datasource (self.allBookMarks). Update the values into self.allBookMarks then reload the table.

**Edited Code**

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle 
forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    [self.table beginUpdates];

  if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) 
  { 
    Hadits *delHadit = [self.allBookMarks objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    dbAccess *dbmethods = [[dbAccess alloc] init]; 
    NSInteger delHaditid = delHadit.haditid;
    [dbmethods deleteBookMark:delHaditid];
    self.allBookMarks = [dbMethods getAllBookMarks]; 
    [dbmethods release];    
  }
  [self.table reloadData];//its not working reload data...
  [table endUpdates];
}
```

Comment: no sir it is not working , it is make app crash ,
before adding this my app delting data .. but when i add this code its stop doing so , any other idea?

Comment: i think you have just refered some other array to allBookmark like this, allBookMarks=someArray, if you remove the object from allbookmark it will also remove from someArray. so do as, allBookMarks=[someArray retain]; then you wont get any crash.

Comment: -(void) deleteBookMark : (NSInteger) delBookMarkId
{ 
 NSString *sql = [NSString 
      stringWithFormat:@"DELETE FROM tbl_bookMark where bmark_hadit_id= %d",delBookMarkId];
 
 const char *query = [sql UTF8String];  

 sqlite3_stmt *resultset;
 
 int sqlResult = sqlite3_prepare_v2(databaseref, query, -1, &resultset, NULL);
 
 if (sqlResult==SQLITE_OK)
 {   
  if(sqlite3_step(resultset))
  {
   // Ok....
  } 
  
 }
 else 
 {
  NSLog(@"Problem with database");
  NSLog(@"%d",sqlResult);  
 }
}
this code is working rite coz it is delting data from db but problem is my tabledata reload not working

Comment: The problem is not with your reloadData function, how you are initializing the array?

Comment: -(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle 
forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
 [self.table beginUpdates];

 if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) 
   { 
     //  [self.allBookMarks removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    Hadits *delHadit = [self.allBookMarks objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
      dbAccess *dbmethods = [[dbAccess alloc] init]; 
    NSInteger delHaditid = delHadit.haditid;
   [dbmethods deleteBookMark:delHaditid];
   [dbmethods release];    
  }
 [self.table reloadData];
 [table endUpdates];
}

Comment: Where you loading the data into array? viewDidload? just paste the code of initializing that array

Comment: dbAccess *dbMethods = [[dbAccess alloc] init];
 
 self.allBookMarks = [dbMethods getAllBookMarks];

 
 [dbMethods release];

Comment: Hmm.. now this is the final solution, dbAccess *dbMethods = [[dbAccess alloc] init]; self.allBookMarks = [dbMethods getAllBookMarks]; [dbMethods release];  place this code before reloading the tableview

Answer (score 0):

What is `self.table`? Is it your class variable for your `UITableView`? You should note that you can also reference the `UITableView` directly since it is passed into that method as `tableView`. I dunno if your `table` variable isn't setup correctly (through Interface Builder) or what, but I'd try using the `tableView` variable.

Comment: yes its my class variable of UITableView, and in nib file tables are assign (handed over) to class variable table....