# tablerow delete but still showon in table view

Tags: iphone, ipad, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4, ios-simulator

my data is show on the table whn i select data to delet its delted from database but not from table , i go back to other view and again come to the delete table view then delete data is not show again
i am using this code ...

```
- (void)deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPath withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation
{

    NSLog(@"Hello");

}


-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle 
forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 

{
//  int row = [indexPath row];
    [self.table beginUpdates];
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) 
    {   
        Hadits *delHadit = [self.allBookMarks objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        dbAccess *dbmethods = [[dbAccess alloc] init]; 
        NSInteger delHaditid = delHadit.haditid;
        [dbmethods deleteBookMark:delHaditid];
        [dbmethods release];
    }       

    [self deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                          withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    [self.table endUpdates];

    NSLog(@"Hello");
    [self.table reloadData];

}
```

...Help needed..
Regards Haseeb

Comment: may i know whats the difference between this question and this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929960/table-reloaddata-not-working

Comment: @KingofBliss I think the question must be closed as it is a exact duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

in view will appear prepare your array which having record and in commitEditing add one line.

```
[self viewWillApear:YES];
```

and in viewWillAppear add this line

```
[yourTable reloadData];
```

after fetching data from db.

Comment: give me your code for view will appear where you prepare your array for showing table.and updated code for commitEditing

Comment: - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

 dbAccess *dbMethods = [[dbAccess alloc] init];
 
 self.allBookMarks = [dbMethods getAllBookMarks];
 
 [dbMethods release];
 [self.table reloadData];
 
}

Comment: ok if you use this line [self viewWillApear:YES];
 in commiteEditing then ithink it should work perfect.So where you got crash.

Comment: on which line your app crashed. and use this line [self viewWillAppear:YES] at last after table endUpadtes

Answer (score 1):

There is little mistake (or I think the relevant code is not shown). You have deleted the entry from the database, but I think you have missed to delete the same from your array which acts as your tableview datasource.

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle 
forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    [self.table beginUpdates];

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) 
    {   
    //  [self.table deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject: indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        Hadits *delHadit = [self.allBookMarks objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        dbAccess *dbmethods = [[dbAccess alloc] init]; 
        NSInteger delHaditid = delHadit.haditid;
        [dbmethods deleteBookMark:delHaditid];
        [dbmethods release];
        [self.allBookMarks removeObject:delHadit];/// change of code 
    }
    //[self.table reloadData];
    [table endUpdates];
}
```

Comment: titles[1685:207] *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-1447.6.4/UITableView.m:976
2011-02-09 15:40:02.933 titles[1685:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (5) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (6), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 0 deleted).'